# Certain icons missing from system dialogues

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, lightdm

### **Certain icons disappeared from my system dialogues box and shell but *clicking them on their place makes correct response*, i.e. they are working correctly no problem**

2 images attached showing the problem -

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOoJo.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKrRQ.png)

I am using gnome as my desktop session and lightdm as display manager and Kali is my OS (debian based).
I think i messed up something while customising my distro, I made my linux a mix of windows 10+7+xp visually ;) . And now i could not figure it out now what happened :/
It will be helpful if any one can figure it out whats happening.

This is my first question here so correct me if i am wrong, & sorry for the bad English.

Comment: I changed my default login screen to that of a windows XP one, changed bootsplash animation to that of Windows 10 & the entire system theme and icons are of Windows 7.
These are the changed I did.

Comment: I think Bill Gates cursed my system for applying windows themming  :|